# Teradata Change data capture

Tags: teradata, capture

My team is thinking about developing a real time application (a bunch of charts, gauges etc) reading from the database. At the backend we have a high volume Teradata database. We expect some other applications to be constantly feeding in data into this database. 
Now we are wondering about how to feed in the changes from the database to the application. Polling from the application would not be a viable option in our case.

Are there any tools that are available within Teradata that would help us achieve this?

Any directions on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We faced similar requirement. But in our case client asked us to provide daily changes to a purchase orders table. That means we had to run a batch of scripts every day to capture the changes occuring to the table.

So we started to collect data every day and store the data in a sparse history format in another table. So the process is simple here. We collect a purchase order details record in the against first day's date in the history table. And then the next day we compare the next day's feed record against the history record and identify any change in that record. If there is a change in the purchase order record columns we collect that record and keep it in a final reporting table which will be shown to the client.

If you run the batch scripts every day once and there will be more than one change in a day to a record then this method cannot give you the full changes. For that you may need to run the batch scripts more than once every day based on your requirement.

Please let us know if you find any other solution.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I also found a similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472147/best-way-to-compare-contents-of-two-tables-in-teradata/2472888#2472888

Answer (score 0):

There is a change data capture tool from wisdomforce.
http://www.wisdomforce.com/resources/docs/databasesync/DatabaseSyncBestPracticesforTeradata.pdf

It would it probably work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Are triggers with stored procedures an option?

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbname.triggername
AFTER INSERT ON db_name.tbl_name
REFERENCING stored_procedure
```

Theoretically speaking, you can write external stored procedures which may call UDFs written in Java or C/C++ etc which can push the row data to your application in near real time.